# Makefile: no rule to make target: how to set the correct rules?

Tags: c++, makefile, build

I have a project that I am trying to create a Makefile for. The folder structure looks like this:

```
|-- bin
|-- build
|-- Makefile
|-- src
|   |-- some_files.cpp
|   |-- some_files.h
|   |-- ForestFactory
|   |-- MMParSet
|   |-- century
|       |-- century_carbon.cpp
|       |-- century_carbon.h
|   `-- grass
`-- src_multithread
    |-- __history
```

and I have tried to use [this reference](https://hiltmon.com/blog/2015/08/01/simple-c-plus-plus-from-makefiles-to-xcode-builds/) to create a Makefile.
The Makefile I have is

```
CC := g++

SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := build
TARGETDIR := bin
INSTALLBINDIR := /usr/local/bin
TARGET := bin/formind

# CPP files
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.cpp)
# remove the src path and add the build path and the .o extension
OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(notdir $(SOURCES))))

CFLAGS := -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++

INC := -I/usr/local/include -I $(SRCDIR) -I $(SRCDIR)/century -I $(SRCDIR)/grass -I $(SRCDIR)/MMParSet -I $(SRCDIR)/ForestFactory

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @mkdir -p $(TARGETDIR)
    @echo " Linking..."
    @echo " $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET)"
    $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    @echo " $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    @echo " Cleaning...";
    @echo " $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)"
    $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)


.PHONY: clean
```

When I try to `make` I get the following error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `build/century_carbon.o', needed by `bin/formind'.  Stop.
```

The source files come from a nested set of subdirectories inside src. My understanding was that the `OBJECTS` variable should contain the complete paths of the final object files, so that I have something like

```
$SOURCES = src/century/century_carbon.cpp ... src/for_branching.cpp ... src/grass/grass_log.cpp ...

$OBJECTS = build/century_carbon.o ... build/for_branching.o ... build/grass_log.o ...
```

Is there something wrong in the way I wrote the compilation rules?

Comment: Probably a case to do some `VPATH` trickery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the *nested* source directory `century`. If you add to the makefile:

```
info:
    @echo " Info..."
    @echo " SOURCES = $(SOURCES)"
    @echo " OBJECTS = $(OBJECTS)"
```

then `make info` gives:

```
  Info...
  SOURCES = src/century/century_carbon.cpp src/some_files.cpp
  OBJECTS = build/century_carbon.o build/some_files.o
```

This check shows that your construction of these macros is ok. And it also shows, as you report, that `make` will then tell us:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'build/century_carbon.o', needed by 'bin/formind'.  Stop.
```

If you add an additional rule, with the directory `century` specified:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/century/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<
```

then your build will proceed.

---

An alternative solution is to use `VPATH`. Add the line:

```
VPATH = src:src/century
```

and also remove `$(SRCDIR)/` from your rule, which now becomes:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<
```

---

**Update:** The above answer could be improved in two ways:

- Use `vpath` rather than `VPATH`, for more precise control of the searches.
- Automatically generate the argument for `vpath` / `VPATH`.

This is suprisingly simple: just replace my hard-coded `VPATH` line with:

```
vpath %.cpp $(sort $(dir $(SOURCES)))
```

Comment: The first solution is not practical because All subdirectories contain sources that need be compiled. But adding all the folders in VPATH seems to do the trick. I still wonder if this is the standard way of doing things because in the end the Makefile I get looks a bit "dirty"

Comment: @Manfredo: I have cleaned up my answer a bit, to make it less kludgey.